# Subset of values in result from RODBC

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I select some values from a Database in R with RODBC like

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=mydatabase, ...')
res <- sqlQuery("select id, class, param1, param2 from table1 ..."
```

For Analysis of the Data I need to select a subset of the data. I got the column `class` which is a varchar and defines some subclasses like `set1` or `set2`.

For example, I need `summary()` for both sets, and then for each set. I would say that this is done by:

```
summary(res) # works fine
summary(res[res["class"] == 'set1']) # does not work
summary(res[res["class"] == 'set2']) # does not work
```

Because I get this instead:

```
Length     Class      Mode 
    10788 character character
```

After filtering I have the data as a long list and not as matrix. What is wrong there?

Comment: It would help if you could paste result of `head(res)` and/or `str(res)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
summary(res[res[,"class"] == "set1",])
```

**Update:**

`res[row,column]` - genrally 1st value is row index, 2nd value is column index, so:

`res[,"class"]` - select "class" column from res.

`res[,"class"] == "set1"` - compare "class" column values with string "set1", this will give *TRUE, FALSE* values.

`res[res[,"class"] == "set1",]` - *TRUE, FALSE* values define which rows to return.

Comment: @reox consider upvoting/accepting as an answer if it was at all helpful.

Comment: Only second coma cause OP code fail. Referencing column by `res["class"]` is allowed (and cleaner for me).

Answer (score 1):

[zx8754 answer shows you what wrong in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453585/168747). Another way of getting it done is to use `subset` function:

```
summary(subset(res, class == 'set2'))
```